# Magento: how to get Paypal transaction ID?

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to print the Paypal transaction ID on our invoice PDF files. Can you pull this information from `$order`, which is an instance of Sales_Order?

I did find some database tables with paypal_ prefix, but all of them are empty, even though we have a real Paypal transaction order in our installation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try :
    $transaction_id = $order->getPayment()->getLastTransId();

Comment: Nice that works! I have 2 questions for you: 1. what's the difference between last correlation and transaction IDs? 2. is there also a way to obtain the credit card processing CSC and VSC result?